# Programmatically unlock certain accounts with Parity?

Tags: web3js, parity, json-rpc, accounts

Using geth it is easy to send transactions from multiple accounts but I do not know how to do this with Parity.

I do not want all accounts unlocked.

I do not want any account unlocked when it is not being used for a transaction.

How can I programmatically unlock (and then lock) an account in Parity?  Using json or web3?  I prefer web3?